# ubuntu 16.04, wireless keeps dropping every 7 minutes

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and the wireless keeps dropping. I have to keep unchecking and checking "Enable Wi-fi" to get it to work. The wireless device is an Edmiax USB device.

Is there any chance of getting this fixed, or do I need to buy a new Windows/Mac computer?

Here's the wireless info:

http://pastebin.com/xLgnE4Jp

Comment: Please run the wireless info script again as some info is missing and post a new link

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and run following commands:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

So what it will do :

1) The `11n_disable` option disables 802.11n features. Adding it to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` makes the change persist after reboots. T

2) The `modprobe -rfv` commands are removing the kernel modules `iwldvm` and `iwlwifi`

3) And finally the last line `modprobe -v` is adding `iwlwifi` back in.

Comment: I'll try it, but in case it doesn't work, is there a way to reverse the changes?

Comment: I tried it, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Don't worry about reversing the change, your wireless will not be affected by the answer